# Linq Any returns true despite all values in the collection being false

Tags: c#, linq, any

I see very strange behavior in properties value calculation.
I have a property HasChanged, which is true if any of it's dependent properties is true.
But I got a result - all arguments are false and the result is true.
I am using MVVM Light framework, and each property is INotifyPropertyChanged

Here are helper functions

```
    private static bool PropertyWrapper(bool value, [CallerMemberName] string callerName = "")
    {
        Logger.Debug($"[{callerName}: {value}]");
        return value;
    }

    private static T PropertyWrapper<T>(Expression<Func<T>> property)
    {
        var compiled = property.Compile();
        var result = (T)compiled.DynamicInvoke();
        Logger.Debug($"[{GetName(property)}: {result}]");
        return result;
    }

    private static string GetName<T>(Expression<Func<T>> expr)
    {
        var mexpr = expr.Body as MemberExpression;
        if (mexpr == null) return "(null)";
        if (mexpr.Member == null) return "((null))";
        return mexpr.Member.Name;
    }
```

And this is the code

```
    public virtual bool HasChanged => PropertyWrapper(new[] {
        PropertyWrapper(() => TitleChanged),
        PropertyWrapper(() => EnglishTitleChanged),
        PropertyWrapper(() => OriginalTitleChanged),
        PropertyWrapper(() => PlotChanged),
        PropertyWrapper(() => OutlineChanged),
        PropertyWrapper(() => DirectorChanged),
        PropertyWrapper(() => YearChanged),
        PropertyWrapper(() => MovieRolesChanged),
        PropertyWrapper(() => GenresChanged),
        PropertyWrapper(() => CountriesChanged)
    }.Any(), "HasChanged");

    public bool YearChanged => this.state == State.Edit && this.source.MovieDescription.Year != this.clone.MovieDescription.Year;
    public bool TitleChanged => HasTitleChanges();
    public bool EnglishTitleChanged => HasEnglishTitleChanges();
    public bool OriginalTitleChanged => HasOriginalTitleChanges();
    public bool PlotChanged => HasDescriptionChanges();
    public bool DirectorChanged => HasDirectorChanges();
    public bool OutlineChanged => HasOutlineChanges();
    public bool MovieRolesChanged => HasMovieRolesChanges();
    public bool CountriesChanged => HasCountriesChanges();
    public bool GenresChanged => HasGenresChanges();
```

and what is written to log

> [TitleChanged: False]
>
> [EnglishTitleChanged: False]
>
> [OriginalTitleChanged: False]
>
> [PlotChanged: False]
>
> [OutlineChanged: False]
>
> [DirectorChanged: False]
>
> [YearChanged: False]
>
> [MovieRolesChanged: False]
>
> [GenresChanged: False]
>
> [CountriesChanged: False]
>
> [HasChanged: True]

It looks impossible dull, but I can't imagine how can it be.
Please, explain me the reason of such behavior.

Answer (score 5):

[`Any`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb337697(v=vs.110).aspx) without parameters returns if there are any elements in the collection. To get what you want you have to check the value of your elements as your [`Any`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534972%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) predicate:

```
public virtual bool HasChanged => PropertyWrapper(new[] {
       //...
       }.Any(q => q), "HasChanged");
```

Comment: Overall correct, but the elements are Booleans, not delegates, so it should be `.Any(q => q)`

Comment: @IvanStoev, thanks, edited. I got confused with so many lambdas there :)